# Convert URI image to base64 format using cordova-plugin-camera

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, base64

Using this function I am able to get the uri of the image from my phone gallery.

```
function getPhoto() {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoSuccess, onFail, 
        {quality: 50,
         sourceType: pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
         destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        });
    }

function onPhotoSuccess(imageUri) {
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';
        smallImage.src = imageUri;

        console.log(imageUri);
    }
```

The console output is showing the uri like this: 
`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A76755`

Is it possible to convert the **imageUri** to base64 format and not using the `<canvas>`?
I am using Andriod phone and this is a cordova app.

Comment: Observed the same issue while accessing photos from savedPhotoAlbum. It works with camera. Using data_uri will not solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`

From the [docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/):

> Return base64 encoded string. DATA_URL can be very memory intensive and cause app crashes or out of memory errors. Use FILE_URI or NATIVE_URI if possible

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change `FILE_URI` to `DATA_URL`
This will give you the image in a base64 format

Comment: The documentation itself states that this is a bad practice due to memory issues.